# Why does Googlebot keep on requesting "value.png"?

Tags: web-crawler, robots.txt, googlebot

Looking through my request logs, I see various requests for **/value.png**:

```
66.249.75.199 - - [29/Jan/2013:20:49:01 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 301 459 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
66.249.75.199 - - [30/Jan/2013:05:20:22 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 301 459 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
66.249.75.116 - - [30/Jan/2013:05:20:23 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 440 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
66.249.75.199 - - [30/Jan/2013:05:20:23 +0000] "GET /value.png HTTP/1.1" 301 457 "-" "Googlebot-Image/1.0"
66.249.75.116 - - [30/Jan/2013:05:20:24 +0000] "GET /value.png HTTP/1.1" 500 651 "-" "Googlebot-Image/1.0"
66.249.75.116 - - [30/Jan/2013:11:43:03 +0000] "GET /value.png HTTP/1.1" 500 651 "-" "Googlebot-Image/1.0"
66.249.75.116 - - [30/Jan/2013:14:07:53 +0000] "GET /value.png HTTP/1.1" 500 651 "-" "Googlebot-Image/1.0"
```

And it keeps on and on asking for value.png if you look down the log.

I have never linked to or published this image.

Why is the Google spider requesting this particular image? Especially considering it's not there!

What's going on here?

Comment: Do you use a CMS? Maybe the image is part of its theme? Since when do you control/own the domain? Had you (some time ago) a subdomain where such an image could have been included?

Answer (score 0):

It's always possible that someone, on another site, might be linking to an (nonexistent) image on your server.